# How to use min blendEquation without blending with the background?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl2

I'm trying to render some planes and I want to use `gl.blendEquation( gl.MIN )`. I'm rendering back-to-front and in the render loop I clear the color buffer with

```
 gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

then I get a black background. The problem is that the planes are blended with the background and I can't see the planes because the background has the MIN value.

One possible solution is draw the first plane without blending and then draw with blending will avoid the background but I'm using a viewport-aligned slices and I have a problem because the first plane is small in some situations (like in the picture below) and the bigger planes are blending with the background.

Figure
[image: Figure]

If I draw the background in white the problem is solved but I need to draw the background in black. There are some way to do this?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!